# WordPress Import from HTML

Tags: wordpress

I have imported a static html site into WordPress using the WordPress HTML imported plugin. However process was not completed hence many page links are not working. Once I edit the imported page then permalinks are working. It seems alias are not generated for all the imported pages. Is there any WordPress function available to automate the process ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not as I dont know how you set up your old static html site.

Try go to your wp admin site -> settings -> Permalink then pick the one close to your static html site.